reducing noise/interference with EOG circuit
I have been designing an EOG (electrooculogram) circuit consisting mainly of TL072's.
Got a prototype working on breadboards, but the output (being read by an arduino through the analog in pin) was quite noisy, making it difficult to identify consistent readouts.
I moved the circuit to a protoboard, which I think has helped clean up the signal somewhat, but it is still quite noisy.
Here is the schematic in proteus:

all chips in the schematic (U1 - U4) are tl072's, due to how proteus displays these chips however, side A and B of each chip corresponds to one of the op amps present in any given tl072
and here is a picture of the protoboard:

I am unable to send pictures of the readout graph just yet, but will send soon.
So far, I have found adding a 10k pulldown resistor to the output makes the output slightly more consistent.
I can generally see spikes when I move my eyes, but they are somewhat inconsistent, and are surrounded in seemingly random spikes which make consistently identifying movement to create an adc with the arduino a pain.
my questions are:

any ideas on possible areas where noise/interference may be entering the circuit?
is a pulldown resistor the right move? was planning on trying some different values when I get a chance
any recomendations for alternative softwares to log the serial output of the arduino? the stock serial plotter isnt great.


Verify if all OPAMP's are fed with the "good" supplies ... and well decoupled by capacitors.

Was C3/C4 meant to be wired in a Sallen-Key filter topology? Also check U1B. You probably want some EMI filtering at the input, and supply bypass as mentioned.

@TimWilliams Yes, its part of a band pass filter.

@Antonio51 could you please elaborate on "good" supplies? if you mean VCC, they are all fed by the 3.3v rail on the arduino uno (not pictured) that is doing the processing for the signals. Also, what do you mean by "well decoupled"? Apologies, I am still new to circuit design, but hoping to learn and improve through these kinds of projects

@KPUGGaming Is that 3.3 V total or is it +/- 3.3 V? The TL072CP has a minimum supply voltage of 4.5 V.

I am currently using 3.3V and GND and the supply voltages. It seems to be working other than the noise with those supplys. Is the minimum supply not 2.25V? I can test it with +5V and GND later and will report back

@KPUGGaming It's +/- 2.25 V

@KPUGGaming  "good" supplies means in the schematic "are the pins supplies of the opamps well wired to supplies ? "Well decoupled" means that a 0.1uF to 1uF is wired directly with opamps power supply pins. I don't see capacitors.

@Antonio51 so, would a decoupling capacitor go between the positive supply and negative supply pins of each tl072?

@KPUGGaming Yes, it should be necessary, for "many" reasons.

@Burglups Thank you, it may or may not have been the third revision following me accidentally destroying two other protoboards, but In the end I think I did a decent job. Thanks for the info, is a bypass capacitor the same as the decoupled capacitor recommended by @Antonio51? or is this something different?

@Burglups also: my french is sadly not that good lol, what do you mean by "Avoir 'over-crossing' components and wires? Is it bad to do so? just seemed most efficient to me when laying things out lol. I added some insulation to some of the pins that would overlap to ensure overlapping components didnt unintentionally connect

@Burglups alright, thank you, will consider that when designing version 2 (which may end up being sooner than I thought) I just wanted to ask, in reference to the 100nF cap you mentioned in your first comment, how did you come to the conclusion of a 100nF cap? is there an equation for this? is it just a well informed guess based off the use of a +5v supply? thank you

Note that a decoupling capacitor (1 uF) should also be used at the junction point of R12 and R13 (VREF) ... and ground.

Note that U1B is not well wired ...

Excepted last two opamps and some others ... not well wired.
Watch the power supplies, "Vcc+" wired to pin 8, "Vcc-" wired to pin 4.
Here is the DC behavior of the system, note Vref (= now to zero) was changed.
The initial position does not work "well". Note: did not test.
Changed also U1B wiring ... and one resistor (your R14 -> 10k).
These two changes should be confirmed (?) after testing.

The latest stages are ok (supplies ! )
Here is the simulation.

I added some resistors (rr1 to rr4) to take account of some "parasitics" ...
Needed for simulation, those can be changed.

UPDATE: Here is the "end" circuit ... It can be improved.


NB: the last "100k, 200k, 300k, 500k, 1 Meg" can be changed.

thank you for this,
few quick questions: 1. where is the final op amp? U4:b? 2. could you please elaborate on how/why the last two opamps are not well wired? 3. is the circuit in your photo running on +15v now? and why is Vref now 0?

also: why was R14 changed to 10k?

1- the final opamp should be added later ... 2- The final opamp U4 is not well polarized, U4A not well wired (? feedback to input + ?), see for supplies pins, page 7 of https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tl072.pdf?ts=1727693285549&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTL072%252Fpart-details%252FTL072CP  3- yes, the opamps are running with +/- 15V ... Tested with Vref=0 ... Should be confirmed. R14 changed to 10 k ... to be confirmed later.

being honest, I am very confused with what those images you added are. The first one is a copy of the circuit I linked without the final amplification stage right? so it just ends at the band pass. but the second set of photos you linked have be confused

Ok. Will add another picture of behavior for the first part.

really sorry, but still very new to this. What are those graphs illustrating, I can see its a voltage over time graph, but I am confused on where each line is being probed from (where in the circuit each lines value is being found) and why this is being tested with a 15v supply instead of a +5v supply

Sorry. I saw Vcc+ and Vcc- ... I think "always" first with 2 power supplies. If this circuit uses only one, just change the Vref at 2.5V (change label place at mid-supply with a decoupling capacitor added) and supply with 5V. It should then be ok.

going to design a new v2 circuit, what all should I add/change from the current setup? so far I am adding 1. decoupling capacitors (100nF) between the power rails of each tl072 (between VCC+ and VCC- (GND)) 2. adding a potentiometer in place of R20 (I think we are having issues operating too close to the upper limit of the amp output which is degrading readings as most readings we are getting are around 3.5 volts which should be the upper limit of output with a +5v/GND supply. Is there anything else I need to add?

Pay attention to U1B (not well wired, inputs are swapped). Don't add a potentiometer (R20) but use "paralleled" resistors (10k, 20k, 30k, 50k, 100k) you can choose (with a solder point) what you want (more stable).
